# Beautiful Soup web scraping first character a point

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I tried to scrape this:

```
<table class="info">
<tr class="info"><th align="center" class="info" colspan="2">Nachrichten zum Tag</th></tr>
<br/>.</td></tr>><td class="info" colspan="2">Information: Room.
<br/>.</td></tr>2023   07:45 Uhr. colspan="2">Update:
<br/>.</td></tr>><td class="info" colspan="2">Heute.
</table>
```

with beautiful soup and this function: soup.get_text() but the first letter becomes a .

output:
`.nformation: Room. .r., 27.01.2023   07:45 Uhr. .eute.`

expected output:
`Information: Room. Update: Heute.`

Comment: How was your HTML generated? What you've posted is malformed

Comment: Because it's not valid html [the first `td` tag is closed without opening], bs4 will parse it to [something a bit different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBlsA.png), but it should not omit letters from the [extracted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERkCy.png). Can you please share the exact html used, and/or more of your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the HTML script seems to be damaged.

I think the correct HTML you need is.

```
<table class="info">
<tr class="info">
    <th align="center" class="info" colspan="2">Nachrichten zum Tag</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="info" colspan="2">Information: Room. </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="info" colspan="2">Update: Heute. </td>
</table>
```

Beautiful soup will behave the way you want it to with this HTML.